Wordpress create-block WP_Block_Type_Registry::register was called incorrectly. Block type names must contain a namespace prefix
I am currently getting into Wordpress and I did most of the developer recources and they work just fine in isolation. My current problem is the block creator. When I try to use my @wordpress/create-block plugin with npx wp-env start it works just fine and can be used but when I try to get any block to work in another local development I get the message from the title.
I tried setting up a new enviornment using ddev (https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/quickstart/#wordpress) then I switched to Local as I have seen a lot of people use it during my search for an answer but that resulted in the exact same situation. When looking up solutions for this error I figured out that there have been like 3 or 4 different reasons for this error but none of theme seem to still apply or be relevant to my usecase. The tutorial (and other video recources) suggest that it should be as simple as haveing a local working setup for wordpress navigate to the plugins folder and use npx @wordpress/create-block@latest and then walk through the steps in the terminal (Or set some flags alternatively). This then creates a plugin that can be activated which is nice and dandy. The php script in that plugin is confirmed to run as expected (Except the block register function) but then there is no block showing up in the block editor (and it does seem to work as simple as that in all the other recources)
I am running the WP version 6.5.4 and everything else (from php to node) is all on the latest version aswell.
Did anyone else have this issue? Help would be greatly appreciated as I am at my wills end. Or a direction where to look for the next step? Since it is working in the isolation of wp-env the function itself seems to work. I echoed the content of the given path in case it might get confused after the build task but that also displays the correct json.
Use a basic wp setup and try to create a new block using npx @wordpress/create-block@latest
for some reason i cant add code tho this question as it wont allow me to format it correctly(?) but all the code is the basic generated code so if anyone got some time to test and maybe reproduce it it would be very much appreciated...
